# Trying to make a function with javascript to enlarge an image

Tags: javascript, image, function

I've got this function:

```
function zoomImage(i, image, currentWidth, currentHeight, targetWidth, targetHeight){
    var widthStep = (targetWidth - currentWidth) / 100;
    var heightStep = (targetHeight - currentHeight) / 100;
    var newWidth = Math.ceil( currentWidth + i * widthStep );
    var newHeight = Math.ceil( currentHeight + i * heightStep );
    i++;
    var imageZ = document.getElementById(image);
    imageZ.style.width = newWidth+"px";
    imageZ.style.height = newHeight+"px";
    while( i <= 100 )
        t = setTimeout("zoomImage(i, image, currentWidth, currentHeight, targetWidth, targetHeight)",10);
}
```

Called like this:

`zoomImage(0, "image1", 200, 150, 260, 195);`

But for some reason the page won't stop loading and crashes eventually. Also the image doesn't get bigger. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Every time the function is run "i" goes up one, and the function only gets run again if i <= 100. Then the function should run only 100 times, no?

Comment: Why do you want it to run multiple times?

Comment: AH it's supposed to be an if, not a while. Dx

Comment: I changed it to an if and now it loads, but now I have the problem that the image doesn't get bigger. It stays at currentWidth and currentHeight.

Comment: @BobM: That's because you're not passing the incremented `i` in the recursive call. The code will look for an `i` in the global scope. If there isn't a global `i`, you should be getting a `ReferenceError`.

Comment: Ah I get it now, unfortunately your anonymous function idea didn't work either though. Hmm...

Comment: @BobM: It [works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/BfBCW/).

Comment: I didn't remove the double quotes in the timeout! It works now, thank you!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you initialized `i` outside the function. That's the `i` that will *always* get passed in when you make your recursive call. This is because when you give a string to `setTimeout`, it is evaluated in the global scope.

This means that the `i++` inside the function only affects the local `i`, and not the global `i`, so `i` is <s>never incremented</s> not incremented beyond 1 + the global value.

Instead pass an anonymous function that invokes the recursive call. This way you're actually passing the incremented `i`.

```
while( i <= 100 )
    setTimeout(function() {
         zoomImage(i, image, currentWidth, currentHeight, targetWidth, targetHeight);
    },10);
```

Of course, as noted in the comments, `while` doesn't seem like the right choice here.

Comment: It doesn't look right.. `while( i <= 100 )`.. but the `i` is never incremented in the loop.

Comment: I didn't initialize the `i` outside the function. It's 0 at the first call of the function and that's it. Then it gets upped one and put as a parameter in the function again. In other words, the second local `i` is the first local `i` plus 1.

Comment: @BobM: But you're not passing the local `i` when you do `setTimeout("zoomImage(i, image,..."`. As I noted in my answer, your string is evaluated in the global scope. If you don't have a global `i`, then it would surprise me that the first recursive call(s) would work at all, since they'll be passing `undefined` as the value of `i`, which should prevent the `while` from running again.

Comment: @Esailija: Yes, the `while` loop certainly isn't right. I assume it was meant to be an `if`.